# WPF curpos in textbox databinding to label

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2012

This Morning i came across a slight problem, now as I'm relatively new to `WPF` i wanted to find out how to do this.

On my form i have a a textbox, and i have a label that i want to bind the current curpos of the textbox to in realtime (as the cursor moves the table updates but only for the textbox).

Has anyone got any idea of how to do this?

Here is some sample code of my textbox in wpf and what i have attempted in c#.

`wpf:`

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="465" Width="681">
<Grid>
    <ListBox x:Name="listbox1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="405" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="208" PreviewMouseDown="listbox1_PreviewMouseDown">
        <ListBoxItem Content="Gordon"/>
        <ListBoxItem Content="Nico"/>
        <ListBox.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ListBoxItem}}">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsMouseOver,RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" 
                     Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="True" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </ListBox.Resources>
    </ListBox>
    <TextBox x:Name="textbox1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="405" Margin="289,10,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="364" SpellCheck.IsEnabled="True" Cursor="IBeam" AcceptsReturn="True" AllowDrop="True" DragEnter="textbox1_DragEnter" Drop="textbox1_Drop" PreviewMouseUp="textbox1_PreviewMouseUp"/>
    <Label x:Name="label1" Content="" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="241,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>

</Grid>
```

`C#`

My events fire in the `PreviewMouseDown` event

```
    private void listbox1_PreviewMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        Point curpos = e.GetPosition(textbox1);
        if (listbox1.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
        {
            ListBoxItem mySelectedItem = listbox1.SelectedItem as ListBoxItem;
            if (mySelectedItem != null)
            {
                label1.Content = curpos.ToString();
                DragDrop.DoDragDrop(listbox1, "%" + mySelectedItem.Content.ToString()+"%", DragDropEffects.Copy);
            }                
        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't sure if i understand what you are trying to do. Do you want to show the `SelectedItem` from your `Listbox` in an `TextBox` and in an `Label`?

Comment: the cursor position of the cursor in the textbox to label

Comment: i don't think you will ever get the Point in `listbox1_PreviewMouseDown` method you should use your `textbox1_PreviewMouseUp` :o)

Comment: @WiiMaxx what about in the drag enter or mouseover methods?

Comment: it's depending on your needs if you need it always also if you don't drag and drop you should use the mouseover else you should use your DragEnter

Comment: @WiiMaxx i will test it now and let you know the outcome

Comment: @WiiMaxx i added the code below, however why does a textbox curpos start at 0 but after the space it still stays at 0, only after the second space does it change accordingly

Comment: it only change if you move your mouse (at least in my case) like expected. So what is your expected behavior?

Comment: its works 100% except for the issue that only after the second character is inserted does it go from 0 to 1

Comment: it's Zero based index so it isn't an issue it's like IndexOf()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i added the following code:

```
    private void textbox1_PreviewMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Point curpos = e.GetPosition(textbox1);
        int pos1;
        pos1 = textbox1.GetCharacterIndexFromPoint(curpos, true);
        label1.Content = pos1.ToString();
    }
```